# Changing Date Format within the concatenate function

Tags: excel

I'm using data from two cells and using concatenate to compile them into a string.

The function cell looks something like

```
=CONCATENATE("",A2,"_",B2,"_AuditD",".csv")
```

Cell A2 contains a simple string and Cell B2 has a formatted date (yyyymmdd)

But the cell shows

```
Fort Hill_42108_AuditD.csv
```

instead of

```
Fort Hill_20150414_AuditD.csv
```

Is there any work around?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `TEXT()` formula to format a date into a string. In your formula it would look like:

```
=CONCATENATE("",A2,"_",TEXT(B2, "YYYYMMDD"),"_AuditD",".csv")
```